# Pass input value to another page in codeigniter without using form and session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass input value to another page without using **form** and **session**.

```
<input class="mtext-104 cl3 txt-center num-product" type="number" name="num-product" value="1">

<?php 
     echo "<a href='http://waljon.com/shop/cart/?id=".$row->id."/?qty=".$this->input->get('num-product')."' class='flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-addcart-detail'>Add to Cart </a>" 
?>
```

How would i achieve this ?

Comment: what is the issue now?

Comment: use the get method. you send the data using Url.

Comment: You can also pass the variable to the controller and then call the view from the specific controller